# gwt ScrollPanel in TabPanel: no vertical scrollbar

Tags: css, gwt, scroll, uibinder

**EDIT**

I have fixed the whitespace behaviour by resizing components within the `VerticalPanel`, that seem to have had an effect on the panel's dimension somehow missed by the console. I don't quite understand how.

However, I am still stuck with none of my panels showing vertical scroll bars.

In a GWT project, I have the following structure:

**Page**

```
DockLayoutPanel
    North (header)
    Center (body)
    South (footer)
/DockLayoutPanel
```

**Body**

```
SplitLayoutPanel$1
    West
        SplitLayoutPanel$2
             North
             Center
                 TabPanel
                     ScrollPanel
                         VerticalPanel
                             -Several widgets-
                         /VerticalPanel
                     /ScrollPanel
                 /TabPanel
             /Center
        /SplitLayoutPanel$2
    /West
    Center
/SplitLayoutPanel$1
```

My problems are with the `ScrollPanel` in the `TabPanel`, which in itself contains a `VerticalPanel` containing several widgets. This is true for each `Tab` in the `TabPanel`.

My problem is that, while the width's for all containers in `SplitLayoutPanel$2`'s center have 100% width, the `ScrollPanel` contains a horizontal scrollbar with a considerable white area next to it's `VerticalPanel`, while they are in absolute metrics the same size.

**Illustrating the situation**

[image: overview of the TabPanel]

This is the `TabPanel`, with `ScrollPanel`, and `VerticalPanel`. Notice how the horizontal scrollbar exists, while the `TabPanel`, `ScrollPanel` and `VerticalPanel` have the same width. Scrolling to the right yields a white area.

[image: Scroll- and Vertical panel details]

The `ScrollPanel` and `VerticalPanel` all sport an absolute width of 598px. The West component of the `DockLayoutPanel` has a size of 600, so that matches. Also notice how bringing up the developer console has made the scrollbar disappear. In fact, the entire panel has disappeared behind it, and no vertical scrollbar pops up.

[image: Scrolled]

When scrolling the bar to the right, the `VerticalPanel` gets partially placed off screen, and the `ScrollPanel` shows this whitespace. Obviously, I don't want the whitespace to be there, so there won't be need for a scrollbar at all. All panels in this situation still have the same width: 598px. Resizing the `SplitLayoutPanel`, using the border to the right, increases these values (obviously), but the panels do still share equal width and the whitespace remains the same size, while I'd expect it to get wider too.

The second tab contains a load of text, which continues off the screen, but no scrollbars appear.

**Problem conclusion**

- No vertical scrollbars
- A horizontal scrollbar with some magically summoned whitespace
- Compontents claim to have equal width

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Have tried resizing the `VerticalPanel` to 90 or 80% width. The whitespace seems unaffected and it shows that 100% really covers the visible width and not more.

Comment: Have you tried `TabLayoutPanel` instead of `TabPanel`?

Comment: I just tried and was surprised with a pretty vertical scroll bar. It appears then it is something with the TabPanel. I also noticed (wrote the code long time ago), that it is in fact a GXT tab panel, as I failed to mention...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TabPanel` (at least the one from GWT proper) resizes from the inside-out: its size varies depending on the size of the selected tab. So your `ScrollPanel` will never have a vertical scrollbar unless you explicitly give it a size, and your content is actually overflowing the *layer* of the `SplitLayoutPanel` you put the `TabPanel` in.

Layout panels, such as `TabLayoutPanel`, on the other hand resize from the outside-in: the `SplitLayoutPanel` would set the size of the `TabLayoutPanel` in its center region, and the `TabLayoutPanel` would in turn set the size of the `ScrollPanel`, so if the content of the `ScrollPanel` overflows, a vertical scrollbar appears.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation. Will try again with this knowledge and get back.

Comment: Apparently, sencha's widgets need to be in sencha windows in order to behave correctly concerning (re)sizing. Therefore, I have rewritten almost the complete UI, but with the `TabLayoutPanel` from GWT since the GXT `TabPanel` does not support flexible sizing. Thanks for providing your explanation!

(This is where I found out about the GXT widgets and panels: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243630-ToolBar-not-resizing-properly)

Answer (score 2):

**First Point :** Don't mix and match layout panels and non - layout panels.

**Second Point :** If you want proper resizing and scrollbars, always try to mention width and height in percentages.

I see that you have mentioned width to be `100%`. But what about the `height`?

What I suggest for you is,

Change `TabPanel` to `TabLayoutPanel`

Set all the panels height throughout the heirarchy as `100%`