# Mixing Panels in UI Service

Tags: google-apps-script

I ave been trying to start a new web app project of mine.  I wanted to start making my main user interface first using GAS, UI Service.

But after mixing to types of panels, it doesn't seem to work.

What on earth am I doing wrong.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var westPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
  .add(app.createButton("Button 1"))
  .add(app.createButton("Button 2"))
  .add(app.createButton("Button 3"));

  var centerPanel = app.createVerticalPanel()
  .add(app.createHTML('Some Text.....'));

  var splitPanel = app.createSplitLayoutPanel()
  .addWest(westPanel, 150)
  .add(centerPanel)
  .setHeight('100%').setWidth('100%');

  var tabPanel = app.createDecoratedTabPanel()
  .add(splitPanel, 'Finances')
  .setHeight('100%').setWidth('100%');

  app.add(tabPanel);

  return app;
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: have you tried SplitLayoutPanel alone ? doesn't seem to work... some widgets have been deprecated, not this one but maybe it should be ;-) ? tabPanel is ok though.

Comment: @Serge SplitLayoutPanel does work. I use it in an app of mine. It just doesn't work with a TabPanel as parent.

Comment: Thanks @Henrique, I had no luck in my tests using it alone with just a couple of labels.... but I guess I must have been doing something wrong: -(  I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Serge As a quick test, the code above works if you remove the tabPanel part and `app.add(splitPanel)`.

Comment: That's what I tried but it shows a beautiful blank screen... am I missing something?

Comment: @Serge I have just published this code, please [try it](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwx0kerCJiIFiljm5J15YuNEEPqNcaL_R91AGEe34o4AKn0nZg/exec). Here's [the code](https://script.google.com/d/1TAlUUvuNwRYHfYfU6INkMyvHW2mDAKH_pfyMeXv6rjvZchd3xxRi4Nee/edit?usp=sharing), I have shared it with you.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it works well... don't know why it fails last time, I must have been doing something wrong . Thanks, could be useful ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps Script UiApp uses GWT behind the scenes. And the issue here is that the SplitLayoutPanel (a GWT *layout* panel) does not work with TabPanel (a *non-layout* panel). My understanding is that the first asks for the height of the parent which in turn asks for the height of the child. Nobody gets happy and the panels collapse.

If we had in Apps Script the GWT TabLayoutPanel it would be the solution for you. But we don't, and don't even bother requesting any enhancement for UiApp on the issue tracker as they (the Google Apps Script team) have stated multiple times that they're not going to put any effort into it, because the way to go is HtmlService. If you find an unworkable situation, do it in HtmlServices or don't use Apps Script.

Here's a good explanation on why this does not work: [gwt ScrollPanel in TabPanel: no vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200138/gwt-scrollpanel-in-tabpanel-no-vertical-scrollbar)